# Plot multiple variable on y axis in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R but have some experience with matlab. I am trying to make comparison plots between three different area measurements on one graph faceted by genotype of animal model. I would like to plot Glom.Area, Glom.Tuft, and Mesangial.Area faceted by genotype (control v Cre -).

My code so far:

```
# Setup
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(readxl)

# work space
setwd("C:/Users/k_nic/OneDrive/Desktop")

# Read in csv file
t1 <- read.csv("sample.csv", header = TRUE)

# plot for one varible
ggplot(t1, aes(x = Genotype, y= Glom.Area))
```

Dataset:

```
   Genotype Sex Glom.Area Glom.Tuft Mesangial.Area
1   Control   M  6617.669  3804.877       1917.310
2   Control   M  7986.696  5377.977       2761.949
3   Control   M  8617.410  4443.345       2335.244
4   Control   M  7785.355  4307.021       2381.512
5   Control   M  9159.720  5568.449       3163.232
6   Control   M  8484.327  5314.041       3238.861
7   Control   M 10315.521  6105.294       3429.906
8   Control   M  5517.161  3090.970       1878.288
9      Cre-   M  6075.166  3438.421       2147.758
10     Cre-   M  8947.698  5809.953       3744.117
11     Cre-   M  6677.471  4315.344       2113.502
12     Cre-   M  7616.932  4293.291       2763.791
13     Cre-   M  8191.464  4778.529       2159.007
14     Cre-   M  8549.339  6043.961       2922.295
15     Cre-   M 11057.196  6546.740       3771.891
16     Cre-   M  5911.768  3382.556       1754.674
```

This is what I would like it to look something like:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this approach, we pivot the three measurements into long-form data. We map the measurement names to the x-axis and their respective values along the y. Mapping the Genotypes to the fill aesthetic yields the pairs of columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(c(Glom.Area, Glom.Tuft, Mesangial.Area)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value, fill = Genotype)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>